# How to show an activity as popup intent when clicking on notification?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, action, android-notifications

I am working on a reply action from the notification of the text message. Anyone please help me out how to **intent an activity as popup or dialog from notification on click**.
I already add reply option to the notification and intent an activity from it but not getting it as required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also getting the same issue a few days back but now I resolved it by setting the theme of the activity in the manifest as:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

and also add :

```
android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
```

You can simply create an activity layout for the reply and its context activity. On the intent of this activity, the layout comes up as a dialog to the user. As you mentioned that you already intent any activity from the reply action button in the notification, so just replace the activity name with this activity name.

It works surely.